# I am looking for an antivirus software which can scan the BIOS/UEFI image ROM

Tags: antivirus, bios

Is there a antivirus software which can scan the BIOS/UEFI image ROM?

Most antivirus programs can only scan the files on disk.

It should run on Linux, Windows or an USB boot stick.

Comment: Could you please elaborate whether you're looking to scan a ROM file before flashing it or planning to scan the BIOS/UEFI ROM of a running system? The latter might not possible in the general sense. For example, an infected system may prevent the OS from reading the ROM or return fake un-infected contents.

Comment: I want to scan an infected system. If the antivirus uses the memory bus to get the ROM it might not be possible for the virus to return fake contents.

Comment: An infected system could trap memory access by entering [system management mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) outside the control of the operating system. An infected Intel Management Engine or AMD Platform Security Processor image could do that as well. Given how hard it is to infect a BIOS/UEFI, I'm going to wager that such infections are rare and use all the available tricks to escape detection, making it unlikely that such an antivirus exists.

Comment: @aitap Maybe some escape detection. But not all. A normal virus (which is not in the BIOS) can also avoid detection.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer in the sense that even though ESET antivirus offers some [UEFI scanning](https://help.eset.com/glossary/en-US/technology_uefi.html) functionality, it does so only for Windows installations and detections can not be removed (a UEFI reflash is recommended). See also [this](https://forum.eset.com/topic/33675-can-an-advanced-bios-virus-be-blocked-by-eset-antivirus/). All consumer-oriented ESET AV products include this functionality.

Finally, even though ESET offers a Rescue (boot) CD, it offers no UEFI scan capability.